# How to draw completely monocolor text with use of Graphics.DrawString?

Tags: c#, string, graphics, colors, drawstring

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(300, 50);
Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
gfx.DrawString("Why I have black outer pixels?", new Font("Verdana", 14),
    new SolidBrush(Color.White), 0, 0);
gfx.Dispose();
bmp.Save(Application.StartupPath + "\\test.png", ImageFormat.Png);
```

[image]

I need text to be completely white. I tried different brushes like Brushes.White and etc, but all bad. What can I do? All text pixels must be white, just opacity can change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved: (use the textrenderinghints in combination with drawstring)

```
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(300, 50);
        Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);

        gfx.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;
        gfx.DrawString("Why I have black outer pixels?", new Font("Verdana", 14),
            new SolidBrush(Color.White), 0, 0);
        gfx.Dispose();
        bmp.Save(Application.StartupPath + "\\test.png", ImageFormat.Png);
```

Comment: I can't afford any blackness. This is for game translation. The game uses white text on transparent color and adds different masks to it. So I must replace it with translated text in a same way.

Comment: Hm, this is what I like more. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

This is because the background of the bitmap is a transparent black. Try to make it a transparent white before drawing:

```
gfx.Clear(Color.FromArgb(0, 255, 255, 255));
```

---

Apparently this does not change anything. Use `TextRenderer.DrawText` instead. It allows you to specify a background color:

```
TextRenderer.DrawText(gfx, "text", font, point, foreColor, backColor);
```

However it might just fill the text rectangle. I'm not sure. Or repeat what we have done above (`gfx.Clear(...)`) with an overload of `TextRenderer.DrawText` that does not have a backColor.

```
gfx.Clear(Color.FromArgb(1, 255, 255, 255));
TextRenderer.DrawText(gfx, "text", font, point, Color.White)
```

---

All these tricks just seem to have no effect at all. The only option left seems to be to disable anti-aliasing. This is done with `SmoothingMode` for non-text drawing (lines circles etc.) and `TextRenderingHint` for text rendering.

```
gfx.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.SingleBitPerPixelGridFit; // For text
gfx.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.None; // For geometrical objects
```

Comment: For some weird reason nothing changes. Did you tested it?

Comment: No. Try `gfx.Clear(Color.FromArgb(1, 255, 255, 255));`. Maybe the `Color` structure is too smart and converts the fully transparent white back to transparent black. A transparency of 1 could do the trick.

Comment: Nothing works again... And the version with backColor simply fills everything with white, but I need white text on transparent background.

Comment: Well, then the only option which seems to be left is to swich off anti-aliasing... `Graphics.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.SingleBitPerPixelGridFit`.

Comment: This also didn't changed anything.

Comment: Ok, I just read the `SmoothingMode` does not affect text. Use `TextRenderingHint` instead.

Comment: Thank you. I this might work. Actually I already coded this: `            for (int i = 0; i < bmp.Width; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < bmp.Height; j++)
                {
                    Color px = bmp.GetPixel(i, j);
                    bmp.SetPixel(i, j, Color.FromArgb(px.A, Color.White));
                }`

Comment: Actually weird, you telling that need to disable anti-aliasing, but  `codemonkey` enabled it at all black pixels gone.

Comment: @codemonkey: Can you explain why your solution works? Anti-aliasing seems to create these black borders; however, you explicitly switch it on!